# Access to root directory in npm package

Tags: npm, directory, package, root

i create a npm package who need to access src/assets/svg/ in root directory.

Exemple of tree :

```
node_modules
  my-npm-package
src
  assets
    svg
```

I want to know if there is a way to access to svg folder from my npm package ?

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths allow you to do that.

You would need to go up from `my-npm-package` to the root, then go down `src/assets/svg`.

The relative path would be:

```
../../src/assets/svg
```

`..` means one level up in the hierarchy defined by the path.

Comment: The npm [install algorithm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install#algorithm) _does not_ guarantee `my-npm-package` will always reside at the top level of the `node-modules` directory. It (`my-npm-package`) may be deeply nested elsewhere in the resultant tree. Further info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/folders#cycles-conflicts-and-folder-parsimony).